# How can I add json data into an array that are comprised of lngs and lats?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, maps

I am beginner to programming. I am building a website that will retrieve longtitudes and latitudes from database.Then It will show points on google map then It will route between points. But I could't store json data in an array.I am getting different errors.

This is my code.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['ajax'] ) ){

        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'id1111790_root'; 
        $dbpwd  =   '12345678'; 
        $dbname =   'id1111790_longlat';
        $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

        $places=array();

        $sql    =   'select 
                        `location_name` as \'name\',
                        `location_Latitude` as \'lat\',
                        `location_Longitude` as \'lng\'
                        from `maps`
                        limit 100';

        $res    =   $db->query( $sql );
        if( $res ) 
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) 
                $places[]=array( 'latitude'=>$rs->lat, 'longitude'=>$rs->lng, 'name'=>$rs->name );

        $db->close();

        header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
        echo json_encode( $places,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyAaWYmMhckn2kI5t-1bM9XkQsg0QxrozWc' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var getacara=0; 
var latLngs = [];
var bounds;
//var latLngs = [];
function load() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: center
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    setRoute();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                $.ajax({

                url: document.location.href,/*'phpmobile/getlanglong.php'*/
                data: { 'id': getacara, 'ajax':true },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( data, status ){
                    $.each( data, function( i,item ){

                        latLngs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat,data[i].lng));

                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                }
            }); 



}

function setRoute() {
    var start = latLngs[0].lat + ',' + latLngs[0].lng;
    var end = latLngs[latLngs.length - 1].lat + ',' + latLngs[latLngs.length - 1].lng;

    var waypts = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < latLngs.length - 1; i++) {
        waypts.push({
            location: latLngs[i].lat + ',' + latLngs[i].lng,
            stopover: true
        });
    }
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });


}

 document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', load, false );
</script>
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas, #map_canvas {
    height: 80%;
}
@media print {
    html, body {
        height: auto;
    }
    #map-canvas, #map_canvas {
        height: 650px;
    }
}
#panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
</style
</head>
<body>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: It says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You told JSON_ENCODE to force everything to be an object so the arrays you created inside of `$places` will now be objects. Therefore process the data you receive as an object.

```
success: function( data, status ){
    $.each( data, function( i,item ){

        latLngs.push(
            new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat,item.lng)
        );
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`) points that you're not getting what you expect when you're trying to use the `lat` property.

Check if the `data[i]` variables have the right values in your `$.ajax` callback. If `data` is not there, it might mean you're not properly returning data from your PHP code, or that the database is not accessible, or that it was empty.

You're also accessing the `lat` property in `setRoute()`. Note that `setRoute()` gets executed **before** the data comes back from the server, so `latLngs` is still an empty array. The `$.ajax` callback will be executed at some point in the future, when your server responds (even if it's quick, for JavaScript, that is "later"). In the meantime, the rest of your JavaScript keeps executing, and `setRoute()` tries to read from `latLngs[0]` but `latLngs` doesn't have anything in it yet.

I recommend you read about JavaScript promises and deferred execution, it may help clear that confusion. You may also want to read about the JavaScript event loop, which will help you understand why some actions are kicked to be executed in the future.